# WPF max width of TextBlock in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wrappanel

I have need to programmatically create a TextBlock inside a WrapPanel.  This TextBlock will act like a heading, therefore I don't want anything to appear to right of the TextBlock.  Is there a better way to max out the Width of the TextBlock without doing something like;

```
myTexblock.Width = 1000000;
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, don't use a WrapPanel.

Comment: @Clemens the WrapPanel solves other problems.  In this wrap panel multiple items need to added in programmatically.  Could be 1 button could be 20 buttons.  It is all based on the data it is being feed.  So if you know a good way to solve unknown number of objects placed on the screen and "wrapping" them please tell me.

Comment: Tell us precisely which layout you want to achieve. Perhaps add a sketch.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution than putting your header in your `WrapPanel` is to place the header and `WrapPanel` in a `StackPanel`

Something similar to this:

```
<StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="Some Header Text"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
      <WrapPanel>

         <Button Content="Placeholder" />
         <Button Content="Also holding a place" />
      </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This gives the same visual effect as what you described without the sloppy property setting.

Comment: This will not work, as there will be multiple "headers" in this WrapPanel.

Comment: @user2891892 So you're telling that you have multiple "headers" stacked vertically? Sounds pretty much like using a StackPanel...

Comment: You should use a StackPanel with TextBlocks as headers (as many as you want) and WrapPanels.

Comment: As @Fayilt said, the fact that there may be multiple "headers" isn't really a good excuse. If you posted a description of what you WANT to achieve it may be easier to provide a different solution that does exactly what you want.